# Can SQL Server Hierarchy type method IsDescendantOf accept multiple input values?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, hierarchyid

I am using the **HierarchyId** data type for the storage of locations. A user may be limited by location (`LocationId`). If the user has more than 1 location limit the IsDescendantOf method on the HierarchyId data type has to be invoked again with an `OR`.

Example(filter Employees by LocationId 5 and 6):

```
SELECT * FROM Employee
INNER JOIN Location ON Employee.LocationId = Location.LocationId
WHERE Location.Node.IsDescendantOf((SELECT TOP 1 Node
    FROM Location 
    WHERE LocationId = 5)) = 1
OR 
Location.Node.IsDescendantOf((SELECT TOP 1 Node
    FROM Location 
    WHERE LocationId=6)) = 1`
```

This works fine for 2 `LocationId` filters but what if this grows and a person has say 10 filters. Can IsDescendantOf work like the sql `IN` clause?

Tables used:

```
CREATE TABLE Location (
LocationId int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
Name       nvarchar(100) NOT NULL,
[Node]  hierarchyid    NOT NULL,
[ParentNode]  AS ([Node].[GetAncestor]((1))) PERSISTED,
[Level]  AS ([Node].[GetLevel]()) PERSISTED,
);
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Employee] (
[EmployeeId] [int] PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[LocationId] [int] NULL,
[Name] [nvarchar](50) NULL
) ;
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Note**: I addes the second solution (point 6).

1. You may use a table variable to store all searched locations (ex. `DECLARE @SearchedAncestorLocation TABLE(LocationId INT PRIMARY KEY)`).
2. You have to find `HIERARCHYID's` nodes for every location ID from `@SearchedAncestorLocation`.
3. You have to do an `INNER JOIN` with employee's location using this filter: `employee_location.Node.IsDescendantOf(searched_location.Node) = 1`.
4. I think you should add an `UNIQUE(Node)` constraint to `Location` table to prevent duplicated locations (duplicated nodes).
5. **First solution**: [demo here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/69151).

```sql
    DECLARE @Location TABLE(
    LocationId  int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    Name        nvarchar(100) NOT NULL,
    [Node]      hierarchyid    NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE ([Node])
    );
    
    DECLARE @Employee TABLE (
    [EmployeeId] [int] PRIMARY KEY,
    [LocationId] [int] NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](50) NULL
    );
    
    INSERT  @Location(LocationId, Name, [Node])
    VALUES  ( 1, N'A',     '/1/'),
            ( 2, N'AA',    '/1/1/'),
            ( 3, N'AA-1',  '/1/1/1/'), -- <-- First employee  @ AA-1
            ( 4, N'AA-2',  '/1/1/2/'),
            ( 5, N'AA-3',  '/1/1/3/'),
            ( 6, N'AB',    '/1/2/'),
            ( 7, N'AA-1',  '/1/2/1/'),
            ( 8, N'AB-2',  '/1/2/2/'),
    
            ( 9, N'B',     '/2/'),
            (10, N'BA',    '/2/1/'),
            (11, N'BA-1',  '/2/1/1/'), -- <-- Second employee @ BA-1
            (12, N'BA-2',  '/2/1/2/'),
            (13, N'BA-3',  '/2/1/3/'),
            (14, N'BB',    '/2/2/'),
            (15, N'BB-1',  '/2/2/1/');
    
    INSERT  @Employee(EmployeeId, [Name], LocationId)
    VALUES  (1,  N'Ion Ionescu',   3), -- AA-1
            (2, N'Geo Georgescu', 11); -- BA-1
    
    DECLARE @SearchedAncestorLocation TABLE(LocationId INT PRIMARY KEY);
    INSERT  @SearchedAncestorLocation 
    VALUES  (1), --A 
            (2), --AA
            (3), --AA-1
            (9), --B
           (10), --BA
           (14); --BB
    
    SELECT  e.*, 
            el.Name             AS EmpLocationName,
            el.Node.ToString()  AS EmpLocationHID,
            s.LocationId        AS SearchedLocationId,
            sl.Name             AS SearchedLocationName,
            sl.Node.ToString()  AS SearchedLocationHID
    FROM    @Employee e
    INNER JOIN  @Location el ON e.LocationId = el.LocationId
    INNER JOIN  @Location sl ON el.Node.IsDescendantOf(sl.Node) = 1
    INNER JOIN  @SearchedAncestorLocation s ON sl.LocationId = s.LocationId 
    --AND           sl.Node <> el.Node
```

Results:

```
EmployeeId LocationId  Name          EmpLocationName EmpLocationHID SearchedLocationId SearchedLocationName SearchedLocationHID
---------- ----------- ------------- --------------- -------------- ------------------ -------------------- -------------------
1          3           Ion Ionescu   AA-1            /1/1/1/        1                  A                    /1/
1          3           Ion Ionescu   AA-1            /1/1/1/        2                  AA                   /1/1/
1          3           Ion Ionescu   AA-1            /1/1/1/        3                  AA-1                 /1/1/1/
2          11          Geo Georgescu BA-1            /2/1/1/        9                  B                    /2/
2          11          Geo Georgescu BA-1            /2/1/1/        10                 BA                   /2/1/
```

Results if you uncomment the last line (`AND sl.Node <> el.Node`):

```
EmployeeId LocationId  Name          EmpLocationName EmpLocationHID SearchedLocationId SearchedLocationName SearchedLocationHID
---------- ----------- ------------- --------------- -------------- ------------------ -------------------- -------------------
1          3           Ion Ionescu   AA-1            /1/1/1/        1                  A                    /1/
1          3           Ion Ionescu   AA-1            /1/1/1/        2                  AA                   /1/1/
2          11          Geo Georgescu BA-1            /2/1/1/        9                  B                    /2/
2          11          Geo Georgescu BA-1            /2/1/1/        10                 BA                   /2/1/
```

6. **Second solution**.

```sql
    SELECT  e.EmployeeId,
            e.LocationId,
            e.Name
    FROM    @Employee e
    INNER JOIN  @Location el ON e.LocationId = el.LocationId
    WHERE EXISTS 
    (
            SELECT  *
            FROM    @SearchedAncestorLocation s
            INNER JOIN @Location sl ON s.LocationId = sl.LocationId 
            WHERE   el.Node.IsDescendantOf(sl.Node) = 1
            --AND       el.Node <> sl.Node 
    );
```

Comment: This is fantastic! Thank you very much. I notice though that you get duplicate Employee entites (Ie 3 x the same EmployeeId). Group By doesnt seem to do the trick.

Comment: I used this to filter for duplicates `SELECT  *
FROM    dbo.Employee e
        INNER JOIN ( SELECT DISTINCT
                            ( dbo.Employee.EmployeeId )
                     FROM   Employee
                            INNER JOIN Location el ON Punches.LocationId = el.LocationId
                            INNER JOIN Location sl ON el.Node.IsDescendantOf(sl.Node) = 1 
                            INNER JOIN @SearchFilters s ON sl.LocationId = s.LocationId
                   ) filtered ON e.EmployeeId = filtered.EmployeeId`

Comment: @JeremyChild: Was not clear for me what records do you really need. My query shows all employees and all ancestors (from `@SearchedAncestorLocation`) for these employees. If you want to show (only) employee information you can try the second solution. It should offers a better performance (less logical reads)

Comment: Thank you for your supreme genius!