# HierarchyID - Get all children of a list of nodes

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, hierarchyid

Two tables:

```
Team
----
TeamID    int
TeamNode  hierarchyid

TeamUser
--------
TeamID    int
UserID    int
```

And I have a query to get the immediate teams a user belongs to:

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
Team INNER JOIN TeamUser
ON Team.TeamID = TeamUser.TeamID
WHERE
TeamUser.UserID = 123
```

Next I want to find all child nodes of the nodes from the result set of above query. I know I can use `IsDescendantOf()` to get all children of one node, but not sure how to use that to get all children of a list of nodes.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can SQL Server Hierarchy type method IsDescendantOf accept multiple input values?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10460236/can-sql-server-hierarchy-type-method-isdescendantof-accept-multiple-input-values)

Answer (score 2):

There is a prior question about at least one example you gave: `IsDescendantOf()`

[Can SQL Server Hierarchy type method IsDescendantOf accept multiple input values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10460236/can-sql-server-hierarchy-type-method-isdescendantof-accept-multiple-input-values)

Comment: Thank you, the first solution presented in that question appears to work. I will do some more testing but it looks good with some slight modifications.